# ionic horizontal scroll inside a scrollable ion-content

Tags: ionic-framework

I created several horizontal scrolling lists inside a scrollable ion-content like this:

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
      <div class="reps" ng-repeat="item in data">
            <div>{{item.title}}</div>
            <div class="images-list">
                <ion-scroll direction="x">
                    <div class="image"
                         ng-repeat="img in item.images">
                        <img ng-src="{{img}}">
                    </div>
                </ion-scroll>
            </div>
      </div>
</ion-content>
```

**SCSS**

```
.images-list{
    max-height: 120px;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    .image{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 120px;
        padding: 0 1px;
        img{
            width: auto;
            height: inherit;
        }
    }
}
```

This is displaying well and it's scrolling horizontally for each sub-list.

The problem is that when I try to scroll over lists (vertical scroll of ion-content) it can only scroll over the outside of the sub-lists but not when scrolling over the sub-lists content.

Any help how can I achieve this to scroll from any area of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searches, I found that this is a bug related to ionicframework.
According to this issue conversation https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2501 the bug is fixed and will be available in the next update of ionic.

Comment: I'm still having this issue

Comment: did you fix that issues please help me to do , i tried different ways for this same issues...

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```css
CSS
ion-content{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ion-content scroll-x="true">


</ion-content>
```